# Meteor get usernames from userId, easier method

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Using Meteor:

I have a list of messages in Messages which store a userId.

```
Messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages'); 

// example of message data:

{
authorId: 'XFdsafddfs1sfd', // corresponding to a Meteor.userId
content: 'some Message'
}
```

And I'm publishing both the messages and the existing users.

```
Meteor.publish('messages', function () {
  return Messages.find({});
});

Meteor.publish('users', function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({});
});
```

Currently I can grab the list of messages and add the usernames based on the userIds. Since users can change their usernames & profile information, it doesn't make sense to add user data to the collection, just the userIds.

```
var messages = Messages.find({}).fetch();
var messages.forEach(function(message) {
    message.username = Meteor.users.find(message.authorId).fetch() [0].username; // ugly
  });
```

This code works, but involves a lot of wasteful calls. I want to know how to accomplish this in a better way.

> In Meteor, what is the most efficient & cleanest way to pair user data with a collection containing userIds?

Comment: Do you have control of how messages are created or are you reading an existing mongo database?

Comment: have you read this? might be interesting for you. https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/

Comment: I have control over the database. @tomsp I'll have a look, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is a common use case: storing ids of other collections in the db and using human readable arguments on the UI.

In Meteor the collection.find() function offers to pass a transformation callback for this use case.

```
var cursor = messages.find(
    {},
    {   
        transform: transformMessage
    }
);
```

The transform function can now directly modify your object, to add/modify/delete the properties of your fetched object (attention: don't modify/delete on client side for security reasons: instead use filters on the server side and allow/deny).

```
function transformMessage(message) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(message.authorId);
    if (user) {
        var username = user.username;
        message.username = username;
    }
    return message;
};
```

The great benefit of this way: You are still working with the cursor and preventing fetch(). And of course, cleaner code.

Comment: It seems the remaining problem is that `Meteor.users.findOne()` is undefined. Fake users were added using `Meteor.users.insert()`, and they can be found in the database under `Users`. Any ideas why I can't access any user data from `Meteor.users.find()`?

Comment: `Meteor.users` can be accessed on the server, but not in the shared client/server space when using `transform`. How can I transform the message/user data?